# How can I use just the new setted state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

So I am using github api and I want to use the data from state in a child component, but it will once take the initial state and after the async function is done the data that I setted. 
How can I use only the data from setState ?

```
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <Router>
        <Header jsTrendingName={this.state.data}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    )
```

Comment: Rahul Cristian what problem are you facing?

Comment: It console logs the initial state and after the new setted state. I only need the new setted state.

Comment: @Gim-CojocaruRahul-Cristian check this solved for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624890/6544460.

Comment: nope, it doesnt solve it for me. but it is better written. thanks

Comment: please vote/accept if it's helpful for you.

Comment: @Gim-CojocaruRaul-Cristian pritam's answer should solve it for you. There's no way to "ignore" the first state, however, you can show a loading indicator while the API call is being made. Then, one the API call is made you can instead show the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

If not already, you need to make API calls in `componentDidMount` lifecycle of your component.

> Additionally you should maintain the state of your API call (`isFetching` flag in your initial state).

```js
...
   getJSData = () => {

   // set isFetching to true before API call is made
   this.setState({ isFetching: true });

   fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     // Call your API
     this.getJSData();
  }
...
```

Where your initial state is:

```js
state = {
   isFetching: false,
   data: null
}
```

Then in `render` method, check API call status:

```js
  render() {
    const { isFetching } = this.state;

    if (isFetching) {
        return <span> Loading ... </span>
    }
    // isFetching is false now since API call is complete.
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <Router>
        <Header jsTrendingName={this.state.data}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = { data: []};

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({data: json.items}));
  }

     render() {
    const {data} = this.state;

    return (
      <Router>
        <Header jsTrendingName={data}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    )
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the data while calling the api and saving into the state by checking the this.state.data is not empty.

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
          }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
      }

      render() {
        console.log(this.state.data && this.state.data); // You should wait for data here then log it or use it.

        return (
          <Router>
            <Header jsTrendingName={this.state.data}/>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>

        )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.